# how to use one graph more than 1 time on one page morris js

Tags: javascript, morris.js

how to use one graph more than 1 time on one page morris.js

for example:

```
  element: 'sales_statistics',
```

that is using ID but is it possible to use class instead

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `element` a string, morris will assume its an `id`. Otherwise, you can pass morris a `jQuery` object, or even a `DOM` object. So if your classname was `.sales_statistics`, you could do this:

```
element: $('.sales_statistics'),
```

or

```
element: document.getElementsByClassName('sales_statistics'),
```

A great way to learn about things like that is to look at the source code. The following is a snippet from Morris's `Donut` constructor, and the same logic is seen in `Grid` and other constructors (I found it by doing a search for `element` in the source):

```
        this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
        if (typeof options.element === 'string') {
            this.el = $(document.getElementById(options.element));
        } else {
            this.el = $(options.element);
        }
```